# trouble with creating a method that returns the average of each column of a 2d array (this is in java)

Tags: java, methods, multidimensional-array

Im having trouble creating this method because i just started on arrays and now i have to create a method that takes as an input an 2d array of inters and returns one single array that contains the average for each column? can anyone help?

```
public class Assigment4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     int[][] a = new int[5][5];
        a[0][0] = 1; //rows
        a[0][1] = 2;
        a[0][2] = 3;
        a[0][3] = 4;

        a[0][0] = 1; //columns
        a[1][0]=  2;
        a[2][0] = 3;
        a[3][0] = 4;
        double []summ =(averageForEachColumn(a));



    }
    public static double [] averageForEachColumn (int [][] numbers){

    double ave [] = new double[numbers[0].length];
    int count=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers[0].length; i++){
        double sum = 0;
        count= count+1;
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++){
            count= count +1; 
            sum += numbers[j][i];

        }
        ave[i] = sum/count;
       System.out.println (sum);


    }

    return ave;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `count` should be reset to `0` before the inner loop.

```
count= count+1; // change this to count = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++){
```

Comment: i did but i mean is the rest of the program right ?

Comment: @Dee code seems correct beside that issue, but why don't you just test it?

Comment: i did but i think i need to populate the values?

Comment: @Dee I guess you should populate them

Answer (score 0):

You haven't populated most of the values in the 2d array. There are 16 total values, you have populated 7 of them (one of them twice).

Get rid of `count` altogether, you don't need it.

Change:

```
ave[i] = sum/count;
```

To:

```
ave[i] = sum/a[i].length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified example of a 2x4 array. You can add more values at you leisure.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3, 4},{5, 6, 7, 8}};

    for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        int row = 0;
        while (row  < array.length)
        {
            sum+=array[row++][col];
        }
        System.out.println("Average of values stored in column " + col + " is " + sum / array.length);
    }
}
```

Of course, you can add the result of `sum/array.length` to an array of averages instead of just displaying it.